# How to implement chromedriver in selenium in Linux platform

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Can somebody tell me how to use the Chrome driver in Selenium for Linux platform?

I have my chrome driver location at `username/home/chromedriver`.

My code is:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/username/ChromeDriver/chrome‌​driver");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("facebook.com");
```

The error I am getting is:

> `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException`: Unable to either launch or
>   connect to Chrome. Please check that ChromeDriver is up-to-date.
>
> Using Chrome binary at: `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`
>
> (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: The location of your Chrome driver (`username/home/chromedriver`) and your configuration (`/home/username/ChromeDriver/chrome‌​driver`) don't match. Make sure you use the right path at every location. Apart from this, everything should be ok, this is how I initialize mine Chrome, too. Try re-downloading all the parts once again. Don't forget to unzip the chromedriver package.

Answer (score 26):

From [the official documentation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver:

> ### Requirements
>
> The ChromeDriver controls the browser using Chrome's automation proxy
>   framework.
>
> The server expects you to have Chrome installed in the default
>   location for each system:
>
> ```
> OS          Expected Location of Chrome
> -------------------------------------
> Linux          /usr/bin/google-chrome
> Mac            /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
> Windows XP     %HOMEPATH%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
> Windows Vista  C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
> ```
>
> For Linux systems, the ChromeDriver expects `/usr/bin/google-chrome` to be a symlink to the actual Chrome binary. See also the section on [overriding the Chrome binary location](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities#TOC-Using-a-Chrome-executable-in-a-non-standard-location).
>
> ### Getting Started
>
> To get set up, first
>   [download](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) the
>   appropriate prebuilt server. Make sure the server can be located on
>   your `PATH` or specify its location via the `webdriver.chrome.driver`
>   system property. Finally, all you need to do is create a new
>   ChromeDriver instance:
>
> ```
> WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
> driver.get("http://www.google.com");
> ```

Therefore, [download the version of chromedriver you need](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads), unzip it somewhere on your `PATH` (or specify the path to it via a system property), then run the driver.

Comment: Hi, I have my chrome driver location at "username/home/chromedriver" .So, i have my code

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/home/username/ChromeDriver/chromedriver");driver = new ChromeDriver(); driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");                              The error am getting is ,      org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to either launch or connect to Chrome. Please check that ChromeDriver is up-to-date. Using Chrome binary at: /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: The documentation page that it links to contains no information

Comment: The **download** link doesn't work anymore in the "Getting Started" section.

Comment: @AaronLelevier Thank you, I fixed the links.

Answer (score 13):

We have installed Successfully

```
sudo apt-get install unzip
wget -N http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.10/chromedriver_linux64.zip -P ~/Downloads
unzip ~/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d ~/Downloads
chmod +x ~/Downloads/chromedriver
sudo mv -f ~/Downloads/chromedriver /usr/local/share/chromedriver
Change the directory to /usr/bin/chromedriver
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

Now run the script and add the following in the environment file.

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app| client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :http_client => client) end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
```

Note : Change the chrome driver version according to your operating system type like 32 bit or 64 bit.

Comment: after doing "chmod -x ...", you can just do: "sudo mv -f ~/Downloads/chromedriver /usr/local/bin"

Comment: These instructions are now quite old and the chrome driver version has changed many times.  Make sure your Chrome browser version matches the driver version.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a complete script for Linux 18.04 to install Google Chrome and the chrome driver.  It should automatically adjust to collect the correct chrome driver for the browser.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# install the latest version of Chrome and the Chrome Driver
apt-get update && apt-get install -y libnss3-dev
version=$(curl http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE)
wget -N http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/${version}/chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /usr/local/bin
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install
```

Comment: while executing the last statement, it says `Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?` even though I have given sudo privileges.

Comment: I suspect it was because you already had dpkg or apt running somewhere else.

Comment: Nope. tt that is not the case. rechecked.. I get that error after this line ```Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

Answer (score 4):

For me worked with these commands:

1. Unziped the file ->  unzip -q chromedriver_linux64.zip
2. Force the copy to the directory 'usr/bin' -> sudo mv -f chromedriver /usr/bin

The selenium code was something like that.

---

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/usr/bin/chromedriver");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("https://mvnrepository.com");

driver.close();
```

Comment: Thank you for this simple and to the point solution. I was able to resolve my "chromedriver needs to be in path..." error this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can see small example from [this example](https://github.com/sarkershantonu/Automation-Getting-Started/blob/master/Junit-cucumber/src/main/java/org/automation/Browser.java)

For linux, i downlaod chrome driver and keep as system path variable(or put in exist path folder). And from code i use following ways (add property and initiate with path of chrome driver)

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver");
ChromeDriverService service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
                .usingDriverExecutable(new File("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"))
                .usingAnyFreePort()
                .build();
        try {
            service.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
```

Answer (score 0):

This shell script will assist you to download and install latest chrome driver and google chrome in your Linux.

```
#!/bin/sh
#get latest version
version=`curl http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE)`;
echo 'Currently LATEST_RELEASE:' $version;
#download the latest version chrome driver available as per the above line
wget -N http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/${version}/chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /usr/local/bin
chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
#install latest google chrome 
yum install https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
google_version=`google-chrome --version`;
echo 'Google Chrome Version:' $google_version;
echo 'End of the script'
```