# Running selenium suite on Linux server

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, testng, remotewebdriver

I am trying to run the selenium suite on linux 64 bit server where stable chrome 76 is installed
and facing below error, my code is  running fine in my local mac machine

**Error**

Chrome is Starting
ChomePath :/scratchchrome/chromedriver_linux76_68
Feb 27, 2020 5:19:51 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
Starting ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.68 (420c9498db8ce8fcd190a954d51297672c1515d5-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#864}) on port 8638
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by

malicious code.
unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running,' so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'arusprint05', ip: '100.104.104.153', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.35-1902.3.1.el7uek.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_222'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: #0 0x5612da7d3749

**Java code is**

```
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

            String chromePath=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/";

            String chromedriverPath = chromePath+PropertyfileConfig.getStringValueFromProperty("chromedriverpath");
            System.out.println("ChomePath :"+chromedriverPath);

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromedriverPath);

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
            options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
            options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
            options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");            
            options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            options.addArguments("--headless");
            options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");

            capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary", "<Path to binary>");
            capabilities.setCapability("acceptSslCerts", true);
            capabilities.setCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true);
            capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

            driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

DesiredCapabilities  are out off. Try to use ChromeOptions only. Cross check chrombrowser version respective .exe file and path passed in setProperty.

this will help you [How to implement chromedriver in selenium in Linux platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674092/how-to-implement-chromedriver-in-selenium-in-linux-platform)